# Divide an SBS domain into two

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs-2003

This is effectively the reverse of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/155052/merging-two-companies-windows-server-2003-and-sbs-2008-domains) scenario.

I have an SBS 2003 R2 domain with 20-odd users in it (25 CALs).

The firm is being split into two; five users are leaving.  A new SBS licence and server are being purchased for the leavers.  The new server will be running SBS 2008 but we could put 2003 on first and then upgrade if that makes it easier. [Well, not upgrade as such, obviously]

I can borrow a large VM server (running Hyper-V) if it will be useful to bring up temporary machines as part of the migration.

How would I set about tranferring user accounts, data, email, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Five users? There are tools and means for migrating Exchange boxes, AD accounts etc. But for five users it's almost not worth it.

I would be tempted to do a clean setup on the 2008 box, exmerge the mailboxes to PST and copy the user data over manually. The mailboxes can then be imported to new Exchange mailboxes. SBS can make it fiddly to do it any other way as it has to be a domain controller, it can't be a member server.

Comment: Well, that should have been obvious to me!  +1 and tick.  I'll do that then...